# How to use $or operation with array of sub-documents in mongo shell and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

structure of myColl :

```
myColl : {
  _id : ObjectId,
  name : String,
  params : [{
   _id : ObjectId,
   name : String,
   value : String}]
}
```

I am executing the following on the mongo shell

```
db.myColl.find({"$or":[{"params":{"$or":[{"name":{"$regex":"data"}},{"value":{"$regex":"data"}}]}}]})
```

or executing :

```
db.myColl.find({"query" : {"$or":[{"params":{"$or":[{"name":{"$regex":"data"}},{"value":{"$regex":"data"}}]}}]}})
```

Both of above gives the following error :

`error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $or", "code" : 10068 }`

How to use $or operator in array of sub-documents, in mongo shell.??

I would also like know how to use $or in array of sub-documents if using with mongoose.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dot notation in your keys to target the fields inside the sub-docs:

```
db.myColl.find({"$or":[
    {"params.name": {"$regex": "data"}},
    {"params.value": {"$regex": "data"}}
]})
```